# Regex - Write values in single lines

Tags: xml, sed, grep

I have xml file where structure looks as below:

```
<Column
             sourceColumn="Column1"
             targetColumn="COLUMN1"
/>
<Column
             sourceColumn="Column2"
             targetColumn=
/>
```

Maybe is simple solution how I can get in result in form:

```
sourceColumn="Column1"spaceOr_targetColumn="COLUMN1"
sourceColumn="Column2"spaceOr_targetColumn=
```

Someone can me help? I tried

```
cat file.xml | grep "sourceColumn=\|targetColumn=" |tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/sourceColumn=/\nsourceColumn=/g' >> file1.txt
```

but when I open file1.txt I have structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='\n*<Column\n*|\n*/>\n*' '
NF{
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|\n*/,"")
  sub(/ +/,"spaceOr_")
  print
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making `RS`(record separator) as \n*`<Column\n*` OR `\n*/>\n*` for all lines of Input_file. Then in main program checking if line is not null then remove initial spaces or ending lines. Then substituting spaces with `spaceor_` string, finally printing the value.

Comment: I got:  awk -v RS='\n*<Column\n*|\n*/>\n*' '
awk: D:\...\file.awk:1:           ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: @danio900409, which o.s are you using? Is it windows OR linux?

Comment: I using windows

Comment: @danio900409, oh ok, sorry I have used and tested it on Linux. Could you please get cygwin and then get newer awk version there and then test it once? Let me know how it goes.